# Any source of good object-oriented design practices?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

Is there any website where people share and discuss good examples of object-oriented design?

Ideally such website should be populated with posts of the following structure:

- Concise description of the problem, including definitions, links, etc.
- Several attempts of OO design, diagrams, pseudocode listings (voted up/down by users)

  - Comments (also voted by users)

Currently I'm looking for a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ward Cunningham's [wiki](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?WikiPagesAboutWhatArePatterns) (he *invented* wikis -- the c2.com one was the first one and is still active) has a lot of discussion, especially but not exclusively about patterns (Ward was very involved in the start of the whole idea of design patterns, as well as agile programming and quite a few more things;-). You can start [here](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?WikiPagesAboutWhatArePatterns) for example. It's not as coordinated and structured as you desire (actually pretty chaotic at times;-) but it can be really instructive to follow all the back-and-forth debates.

Answer (score 4):

i dont know if this site has any discussions, but very good articles:

[object mentor (archive)](http://butunclebob.com)

Comment: ObjectMentor is indeed the best resource you can find on the Internet about OOAD: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/publishedArticles.html

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Software-Construction-Prentice-Hall-International/dp/0136291554](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554)

Object Oriented Software Construction - Betrand Mayer

He's the man that originated the Eiffel language, the most complete analysis of OO software construction I've read.

Answer (score 2):

Object Thinking - David West.

Answer (score 1):

Some books that have not been mentioned:

[Larry Constantine's *Structured Design*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0138544719)

[Grady Booch's *Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020189551X)

[Rebecca Wirfs-Brock's *Designing Object-Oriented Software*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136298257)

[Ivar Jacobson's *Object-Oriented Software Engineering: A Use Case Driven Approach*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201544350)

[Kent Beck's *Implementation Patterns*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321413091)

[Steve McConnell's *Code Complete*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

[Joshua Kerievsky's *Refactoring To Patterns*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351)

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't point you to web sites, but I can refer you to some great books :

- [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)
- [More effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X)
- [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/0201633612/ref=s9_wishf_gw_t?ie=UTF8&coliid=I2Y5RU673D89M5&colid=1AGBSZWLABWYG&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=right-1&pf_rd_r=1BBH7D72CV0Z9YZ03VE4&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=481918411&pf_rd_i=915398)
- [Exceptional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615622)
- [More exceptional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170434X)

Of course, those are C++ books, but a lot of concepts in them applies to much more than just C++